# How to prevent my Windows on the other HDD from being added to the boot menu when doing update-grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

It seems that when sometimes I do `apt-get upgrade`, `update-grub` is automatically invoked.

My problem is that I have two HDDs on my laptop/PC. Ubuntu, as well as a 64-bit Windows 8.1, is installed on the first HDD, and a 32-bit Windows 7 is installed on the second HDD. Now I use BIOS provided boot menu to choose which to boot from.

I want to make sure that the 32-bit Windows 7 NOT be added to the grub boot-menu if someday I updates my Ubuntu using `apt-get upgrade`.